# Group by comma separated flield

Tags: mysql, group-by

Is it possible to group over a comma separated mysql field?
i have a mysql database with a column with comma separated ids.

---

```
id  column
33  23,343,12
34
35  12
36  343,12
```

---

now i am searching für something like "find in set"

in group by.

i want to group by column based on comma separated ids to get the result

---

```
column id
''     34
12     35,36
23     33
343    33,36
```

---

i tried combinations of FIND_IN_SET and JOIN combinations but without any result. I know, possible are the ids "noid,12,13,23,343,344"

Comment: Do you have a list of possible values in the column field? If not, then you are in trouble because that's what you need for this to work.

Comment: [list of doom](http://gtowey.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-fix-comma-separated-list-of-doom.html) structures should be moved to a separate table.

Comment: OK, i have a list of possible values. i know, possible are the ids "noid,12,13,23,343,344". And how can i get this work if i know the possible ids?

Comment: Let this be a lesson to design your tables properly.  Things that are supposed to be very easy becomes complicated because of the messed up table.